# windows embedded ce 6.0 dll creation

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, platform-builder

I wants to create winCE 6.0 DLL.
I have installed visual studio 2005, platform builder, PB R2, PB R3.
HOw to create the wince dll.?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Platform Builder to do this - in fact it's definitely the hard way and wrong tool (it will work, but it's like using a backhoe to plant a tulip).  Explaining how to do it is a long list, and when you have it built, debugging will be a nightmare.

Instead, do the following:

- Install Visual Studio 2005 Standard or Studio 2008 Pro (so you get the device compilers).
- Install an SDK for your target device (or at least an SDK for your target processor)
- Create a new C++ Win32 Smart Device Project from the File menu
- Uee the Wizard to select your Platform and select "DLL" in the Application Setting part of the wizard.